# How to use .travis.yml to cancel a Travis build

Tags: travis-ci

For a project certain preconditions have to met before a CI build makes sense. Not all of them can be ensured prior to commit. Hence, to safe resources I'd like to evaluate those preconditions in `.travis.yml` (i.e. using shell commands) and cancel the Travis build if not met.

I don't think it'd be helpful or feasible to start experimenting with `kill` variations in the `before_install` phase. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these checks in your regular `install` commands and have them exit with a failure if the preconditions are not met.

```
install:
   - check_preconditions && actually_build
```

This will result in "failed" builds whenever this happens.  A (slightly silly) workaround is to abort with success, which instead will show a "successful" build even when nothing was actually built.

```
install:
  - { check_preconditions && actually_build; true; }
```